# Symfony: Show jQuery modal dialog when Access Denied

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, modal-dialog

In my website, only a few users have the right to access certain links(ROLE_ADMIN, etc). When logged in as a normal user and trying to access these links, I receive the Symfony `AccessDeniedHttpException`, which means it works.

**The question is, how can I create a modal dialog (jQuery I guess) simply indicating the user that the data is too sensible?**

I don't know how to do it in twig, since I would have to render a variable containing the script? It would be nice to at least know the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understood, you need to open a modal window with some message to a user, if the user does not have enough rights to click(or proceed) to this link, right?

Fast and easy solution:

We have a link like this(for example):

`<a href="{{ path("some_route")}}"> click me</a>`

you could check if the current user has role[(is_granted)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#is-granted) *ROLE_ADMIN*  then show it, otherwise show some specific link with popup like this:
*main.html.twig*:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
   <a href="{{ path("some_route")}}"> click me</a>
{% else %}
   show a link with popup here
{% endif %}
```

You could use [bootstrap popover](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/) or whatever you like for popup.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Comment: This technically works well. But I would also add that when there is multiple routes you need check like this, it makes more sense to have an exception listener so the checking logic is defined centrally and is not linked to your view layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an exception event listener and listen to AccessDeniedHttpException. The response can be set to display an error message or HTML page. documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener).